# When and why to release an object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, retain

I am using these lines in my code

```
NSMutableArray * NewsFeedArray;
NewsFeedArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]retain];
```

Where should I release this `NSMutableArray`, and why do I want to release that object? In my project, I release the object in my `dealloc` method, but it takes more time to do that.

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 3):

```
NewsFeedArray =[[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] retain];
```

This line of code actually bumps your object's retain count up to 2. That is probably why you're experiencing the object not being completely released when you expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

Release the objects you add to the NewsFeedArray straight after you add them. The fact that you add them to an array makes their retain count go up by one. The array 'owns' them, and when you release the array, all the objects that are in it will have their retain count decreased by one (generally releasing them too).

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this when you start (possibly in your `init` method):

```
NSMutableArray* news = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
```

Note that you don't need to retain it.

To add stuff:

```
RandomObject* obj = [[RandomObject alloc] init];
// set properties
[news addObject:obj];
[obj release];
```

You can release the new object as adding it to the array increased its reference count.

And finally, you put the following in your `dealloc` method:

```
[news release];
```

Releasing the array will automagically release every object that it holds.